# Determinant of a linear map given by conjugation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose we have two fields $K\subset L$ and $A\in GL(n,L)$. See $L^{n\times n}$ as a $K$-vectorspace, then $$C_A\colon L^{n\times n}\rightarrow L^{n\times n},B\mapsto ABA^{-1}$$ is a $K$-linear map.
What is the determinant of $C_A$?

It seems trivial, but I'm too stupid right now. I could go into deep calculating to get a representation matrix for this linear map and compute the determinant of this matrix, but I'm sure that must work much easier.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Even if I just consider the example $n=2$, $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$, I'm not getting any idea of the determinant without starting to calculate the representation matrix. Does someone have an idea at least to this specific example?

Comment: Why does it seem trivial?

Comment: Just a feeling of mine. Conjugating with a fixed matrix seems like a very natural linear map... Do you think the best way is starting to calculate?

Comment: Do you know how to get the matrix of the linear transformation (with respect to whatever bases you are interested in)?

Comment: For sure. Calculating the linear transformation is just some basic linear algebra, but I don't see how I can get enough information about this matrix with just abstract arguments to determine the determinant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> $\def\GL{\operatorname{GL}}$ **Lemma** Let $K$ be a field and $A\in\GL(n,K)$. The map $\gamma_A^K:C\in M_n(K)\mapsto ACA^{-1}\in M_n(K)$, which is a $K$-linear map, has determinant $\delta^K(A)=1$.

*Proof.* Since $\gamma_A^K\circ\gamma_B^K=\gamma_{AB}^K$, we have $\delta^K(AB)=\delta^K(A)\delta^K(B)$, and then $\delta^K(A)=\delta^K(DAD^{-1})$ for all $D$. In other words, the function $\delta^K$ is invariant under conjugation in $\GL(n,K)$.

Now, if $A$ is diagonal with diagonal elements $\lambda_1$, $\dots$, $\lambda_n$, then the map $\gamma_A$ is $(c_{i,j})\mapsto(\lambda_i\lambda_j^{-1}c_{i,j})$. We see at once at the eigenvectors are the elementary matrices and that the eigenvalues are the numbers $\lambda_i\lambda_j^{-1}$. The determinant $\delta^K(A)$, which is the product of the eigenvalues, is in this case then easily seen to be $1$. We therefore have that $\delta^K(A)=1$ for all diagonal invertible matrices, and it follows from this that $\delta^K(A)=1$ for all *diagonalizable* invertible matrices because of conjugation invariance.

Now, if the field is algebraically closed, then the set of diagonalizable matrices is Zariski dense in the set of all invertible matrices, and the map $\delta$ is regular —it is a rational function in the coefficients— so $\delta$ is actually identically $1$.

If $K$ is not algebraically closed, let $\bar K$ be its algebraic closure. Then of course $A\in\GL(n,\bar K)$ and by what we have proved we have $\delta^{\bar K}(A)=1$. It is easy to see that $\delta^K(A)=\delta^{\bar K}(A)$, so we reach the conclusion we want also in this case. $\Box$

> **Lemma.** Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension and let $N:L\to K$ be the norm, so that $N(l)$ is the determinant of the $K$-linear map $x\in L\mapsto lx\in L$. If $V$ is an $L$-vector space and $f:V\to V$ is an $L$-linear map, let $\det_Lf$ and $\det_Kf$ be the determinants of $f$ viewed as an $L$-linear map and as a $K$-linear map. Then $N(\det_Lf)=\det_Kf$.

*Proof.* We can suppose that $f$ preserves a [complete flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_%28linear_algebra%29) $0=V_0\subset V_1\subset\cdots\subset V_n=V$ of $L$-subspaces of $V$; if not, we can extend scalars to a finite extension $L'/L$ which this does happen, and check that the end result is the same.

Then $\dim_LV_i/V_{i-1}=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, and $f$ induces an $L$-linear map $f_i:V_i/V_{i-1}\to V_i/V_{i-1}$ which is given by multiplication by some scalar $l_i\in L$. We have $\det_L=l_1\dots l_n$.

Now the $V_i$'s are of course also $K$-subspaces of $V$, forming now a *partial* flag in $V$ viewed as a $K$-vector space, and $f$ preserves it.
The determinant of $f$ viewed as a $K$-linear map is then the product of the determinants of the maps $f_i$ viewed themselves as $K$-linear maps. Since we know that $f_i$ is essentially multiplication by $l_i$ on $L$, by definition, $\det_Kf_i=N(l_i)$. The lemma follows from this. $\Box$

In this proof, we are computing the determinant of a matrix by first taking it to a block upper diagonal form, so to speak. We can now do what we really wanted:

> **Proposition.** Let $K\subseteq L$ be a finite field extension and let $A\in\GL(n,L)$. Then the determinant of the $K$-linear map $C\in M_n(L)\mapsto ACA^{-1}\in M_n(L)$ is $1$.

*Proof.* By the second lemma, the determinat in question is the norm for the extension $L/K$ of the determinant of the same map viewed as an $L$-linear map. We computed this last determinant to be $1$ in the first lemma, and $N(1)=1$. $\Box$

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$ we can replace the Zarisky topology by the usual topology, and the same reasoning works.

Comment: The morale of this is that for a lot of purposes we can pretend that all matrices are diagonal :-)

Comment: I don't follow. Suppose $n=2,\,K=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$. As a vec. sp. over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}\simeq\mathbb{R}^8$. So the $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $C\mapsto ACA^{-1}$ should have 8 eigenvalues. However, for your $\gamma_A$, there are only 4 eigenvalues. It seems to me that you are considering the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $C\mapsto ACA^{-1}$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ rather than the natural extension of a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $C\mapsto ACA^{-1}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^8$ to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map defined on $\mathbb{C}^8$.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix with coefficients in a field $K$ and $L\supseteq K$ is an extension of $K$, consider the map $\gamma_A^L:C\in M_n(L)\mapsto ACA^{-1}\in M_n(L)$, which is an $L$-linear map as and such it has a determinant $\det\gamma_A^L$. The problem is to determine $\det\gamma_A^K$. What I am saying is that $\det\gamma_A^L=\det\gamma_A^K$ for all fields $L\supseteq K$, so we can take $L$ to be the algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: (I have no idea why you think I was considering what you call the «natural extension», since it is quite unnatural to do so :-) )

Comment: Solely based on the question's wording, it is *not* asking you to find $\det\gamma_A^K$. E.g., consider $K=\mathbb{R},\ L=\mathbb{C}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&i\end{pmatrix}$. When the conjugation is viewed as a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map, presumably $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ is viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. So, we are talking about a linear map whose matrix representation w.r.t. the basis $\{E_{11},iE_{11},E_{12},iE_{12},E_{21},iE_{21},E_{22},iE_{22}\}$ (the $E_{kj}$s are elementary matrices) is given by $I_2\oplus R^T\oplus R\oplus I$ where $R=\begin{pmatrix}&-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I see what you mean. I sort of assumed it was clear, mostly because I've been playing with change-of-fields like this for a while :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the response and the detailed and expanded answer. To me, the first lemma is trivial ($\det\gamma_A^K=\det(A^{-T}\otimes A)=1$). So I was confused about what you were trying to prove.

Comment: That's a nice way to prove it, but in any case it is in that lemma where things happen! The rest is just formalities...

Comment: @user1551 What do you mean by $A^{-T}$?

Comment: @user26857 $A^{-T}$ is a rather common (albeit still nonstandard) shorthand for $(A^{-1})^T$ or $(A^T)^{-1}$.